# How to assign a number to each person in list?

Tags: python

I'm struggling to think of a function that allows me to assign a number to each person in terms of their hierarchy e.g. person 1 with rank of 1 has a higher no. than other players

```
 People = ["Tz", "Bs", "Ds", "Kk", "Os", "Vs", "Dn"]
```

Comment: where is the rank?

Comment: Why not just check `Players.index(player)`? The lowest index == the highest rank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **dictionary** instead of **list**. I would suggest you use `from collections import defaultdict`. By this way, you can even assign a tuple to one key. Even more, if you just passed the same key multiple times with different values it will store them under the same key.

```
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> sorted(d.items())
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a dictionary for this.
Players = { "Rz": 1, "As" : 2 }
It would be in the format {"player_name": strength}

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it via using a dictionary, but there's also a design pattern where you'd use a second list.

```
players = ["Rz", "As", "Ts", "Dk", "Ms", "Ss", "Pn"]
strength = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

This would mean you can access the first players strength by its index in the players list.

```
players[0]
strenght[0]
```

This, of course, needs you to keep the players in the same order.